# Convergence under probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Is $$P(|(X_n -X)-(X_n-Y)|>\epsilon)=P(|(X_n-X)|>\epsilon/2 \cup |(X_n-Y)|>\epsilon/2)$$
If yes than how? 
I needed to prove that if $ X_n \to X $ under probability and $ X_n \to Y $ under probability than P(X=Y)=1.

Comment: The sets are not equal in general, one is included in the other, and this suffices to complete the proof you are interested in.

Comment: @Did isn't the right one included in the left? but for the proof i require the opposite!as then i would use P(A∪B)<P(A)+P(B) and finish the proof

Comment: Actually, the set on the LHS is included in the set on the RHS (and yes, as I said, this is the inclusion one needs to make the proof work).

Comment: @Did could u give an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|x|\leqslant\epsilon/2$ and $|y|\leqslant\epsilon/2$ then $|x+y|\leqslant\epsilon$ (this is the triangular inequality). Thus, if $|x+y|\gt\epsilon$ then $|x|\gt\epsilon/2$ or $|y|\gt\epsilon/2$.

Applying this to $x=X_n-X$ and $y=X_n-Y$, one gets the inclusion of events
$$
[|X-Y|\gt\epsilon]\subseteq[|X_n-X|\gt\epsilon/2]\cup[|X_n-Y|\gt\epsilon/2],
$$
which implies
$$
P[|X-Y|\gt\epsilon]\leqslant P[|X_n-X|\gt\epsilon/2]+P[|X_n-Y|\gt\epsilon/2].
$$

Comment: cool... thanks!